# How to save base64 jpg file in android?

Tags: android, image, base64, jpeg

I get base64 String as is in link below, with jpeg image. It works for many images, but sometimes not. I tried *Base64.DEFAULT*, *NO_WRAP* and *NO_CLOSE* but nothing works everytime. It works on ios or on pc version.

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(base64ImageData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
try {
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length));
}catch(OutOfMemoryError e){
}
```

another attempt which also doesnt work:

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
byte[] decodedString = android.util.Base64.decode(base64ImageData, Base64.DEFAULT);
fos.write(decodedString);
//line below helps for some images
//fos.write(System.lineSeparator().getBytes());
fos.flush();
fos.close();

Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
imageView.setImageURI(uri);
```

in android file explorer, saved file can be opened on some phones or also in windows os.

image base64 data example http://justpaste.it/pquv

I dont know where can be problem

Comment: add a programming language tag, please.

Comment: I see this kind of behavior only when i'v try to pass the string data through intent (the intent can't carry that much information). Check how you pass the data to the Bitmap conversion method, make sure it is passed directly from the data source.

Comment: I logged String with base64 before _base64.decode_ to console and compare it in notepad, and it is exactly same as it is in response (in fiddler), so this is not problem.

Comment: I tried to remove exifData with ExifRewriter() from org.apache.sanselan and result is still same. Some pictures are working, some not. Pictures uploaded from mobile devices are ok, problem is with some pictures uploaded from desktop

Comment: problem is probably becouse android does not support **cmyk jpeg** images. _BitmapFactory.decodeStream_ returns **skia: --- decoder->decode returned false** https://www.quora.com/Why-does-the-Android-SKIA-library-have-poor-JPEG-decoding-capabilities